# Spring WS - unable to return a JAXB response

Tags: java, spring, web-services

As described in this tutorial: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html

I have a Spring WS method which receives a request:

```
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "HolidayRequest", namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
@Namespace(prefix = "hr", uri= NAMESPACE_URI )
@ResponsePayload
public void handleHolidayRequest(@XPathParam("//hr:HolidayRequest") Object request) throws Exception {
    }
```

and I can read the values passed in.  Now if I try to send a response:

```
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "HolidayRequest", namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
@Namespace(prefix = "hr", uri= NAMESPACE_URI )
@ResponsePayload
public HolidayResponse handleHolidayRequest(@XPathParam("//hr:HolidayRequest") Object request) throws Exception {
    }

    HolidayResponse response = new HolidayResponse();  // JAXB object
    response.setIsApproved( false );
    response.setEmpId( BigInteger.ONE );

    return response;
```

The SOAP client receives a fault response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
     - with linked exception:
    [java.lang.NullPointerException]</faultstring>
          </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

NOTE: I have tried wrapping the response:

```
return new JAXBElement( new QName("HolidayResponse"), HolidayResponse.class, response );
```

Comment: What stack trace do you get on the server side? I'm sure that will lead to the exact line of the problem.

Comment: There's actually no stack trace in the Tomcat logs.  I've concluded that this is down to an incompatibility between JAXB and JDOM, as composing and returning an org.jdom2.Element response works fine.